# useState() setter in React Hooks doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook called `useAddFriend`, here is the code:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import { Users }from '../data/userDummy'

const useAddFriend = () => {
    const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState("default")

    const findUser = useCallback((username) => {
        for(let user of Users) {
            if(username === user.username) {
                setRoomId("newRoomId")
            }
        }
    }, [])

    return { roomId, findUser }
}

export default useAddFriend;
```

The problem is, `setRoomId` never update the roomId. I'm already make sure that it satisfied the`if condition` above. But it always return `default`.

Here is how I use the hook on the React component:

```
const AddFriend = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('')
    const { roomId, findUser } = useAddFriend()
    const history = useHistory()

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    }
    
    const handleAddFriend = () => {
        findUser(username)
        setUsername("")
        history.push(`/${roomId}`)
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is in here:

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value)
}

const handleAddFriend = () => {
    findUser(username)
    setUsername("")
    history.push(`/${roomId}`) // <= This line may execute before the roomId is fully set
}
```

To make sure you get the correct `roomId` after the hook executed, It is recommended to use together with a `useEffect`

```
const handleAddFriend = () => {
    findUser(username)
    setUsername("")
}

useEffect(()=> { if(roomId!=='default') history.push(`/${roomId}`) }, [roomId]);
```

Comment: Thank youu!! Never thought that this problem was caused by `history`. Can you please tell me why or give me some reference. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is hook run asynchronously?

Comment: @AlifRamdani useState ( same with setState in class-component) is async. And they tend to batch multiple update into once. Therefore, it's not really reliable if we treat them as synchronous, and recommend to use UseEffect like I just mentioned

Comment: Ahh, I forgot that setState is async. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove useCallback or pass an argument you wanna update in square brackets

```
const findUser = useCallback((username) => {
    for(let user of Users) {
        if(username === user.username) {
            setRoomId("newRoomId")
        }
    }
}, [roomId])
```

Comment: Hi @Max, Could you please add some references here or some more explanations?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: can you remove history.push ?

Comment: @Max I tried and it still doesn't work. And I also pretty sure that it has nothing to do with the problem